# how to select the first record in every liste with a condition in sqlserver

Tags: sql, vb.net

[image: my table]

How can I select the first record in every list that has the column `siege = false`, order by age?

In this example I'd like to have :

[image]

Comment: could you please more specific? are you looking for a query?

Comment: yes i'd like to get a query

Comment: What have you tried? Something like this might be what you're looking for: `SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM TableName WHERE Column3 = FALSE`. However, it's best to update your original post with query's you have already tried so we have a better idea of what you want. Also have a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) for more help.

Comment: What is the type of column siege (Boolean or Text) ?

Comment: why is this tagged `vb.net`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want select the first record in every list that has the column siege = false order by age, use this query :

```
select elu_liste,elu_ordre
from (
select elu_liste,elu_ordre,row_number() over(partition by elu_liste order by age) as roworder
from MyTableName where siege = 'False'
) temp
where roworder = 1
```

But if you want that result :

```
 elu_liste | elu_ordre 
         1 |         6 
         2 |         3 
         3 |         3
```

You should use :

```
    select elu_liste,elu_ordre
    from (
    select elu_liste,elu_ordre,row_number() over(partition by 
           elu_liste order by elu_liste,elu_ordre) as roworder
    from MyTableName where siege = 'False'
    ) temp
    where roworder = 1
```